# How to retrieve data from restfull wcf web service using javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am working with phonegap and when i fetch the data i found this error in ddms as :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: x$ is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/load_json.html:13
```

Please can anyone help me fetch out data from webservice using javascript in PhoneGap Android.

Comment: put the code of loadjson.html and the json you are reading

Comment: i edited my question please check ..... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ajax with phonegap to fetch data from any web api

[read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

this is how I do this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'your url',
    async: "false",
    dataType: "text",
    timeout: 90000,
    cache: false,
    data: {
        type: "1",
        regId: e.regid,
        lat: lat,
        lng: lon
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //data here is json object use as per ur needs
        console.log("successfully registered with server");
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("some error occoured" + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please give me some help for retriving from json... the above code is for sending the data...

Comment: 05-03 01:24:11.931: E/Web Console(900): Uncaught ReferenceError: x$ is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/load_json.html:13

Comment: @ParvindraSingh you can use same code for retrieving data, use get/post according to your api, and make sure you have included jquery min js file in your code to avaoid errors with $ sign